# Прекращена работа программы Microsoft Visual Studio XAML Designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

При создании нового WPF-приложения (и при работе со старым) при попытке отобразить форму .xaml вылетает ошибка:

> "Прекращена работа программы Microsoft Visual Studio XAML Designer",
>   после этого в Visual Studio можно прочитать текст исключения:
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException [5008] Конструктор внезапно
>   прервал выполнение!

полный текст [ЗДЕСЬ](http://pastebin.com/gSwYmhZU).

Число в квадратных скобках всегда разное.
Только недавно удалил `VS 2012` и установил `VS Enterprise 2015`, в `VS 2012` все работало нормально. Из обновлений студия предлагает обновления только для `Azure`, `Microsoft Office Developer Tools`, `Microsoft SQL Server`.

Система Windows 7 SP1 (активированная пиратская версия). Облазил большую часть интернета - почти ничего внятного не нашел, а то, что нашел, мне не помогло. 
Папку Designer/ShadowCache чистил - не помогает (вернее, она у меня пустая). Пробовал студию переустанавливать, пробовал студию 2013 года ставить - точно такая же ошибка. Из радикальных мер осталось только снести систему и поставить заново (поставить Win 10?).
Еще некоторая информация:

Моя система: Win 7 SP1, установлены все обновления по сей месяц за исключением обновлений, сбивающих активацию.
Студия установлена на одном локальном диске, система - на другом. До этого студия 2012 года тоже была установлена не на системном диске и в ней XAML Designer чудесно работал.

Порекомендуйте, что можно еще сделать, пожалуйста. Может, у кого-то была такая проблема и он ее все-таки решил?

Comment: Попробуйте удалить Visual Studio, затем очистить реестр на нерабочие ключи, удалить временные файлы при помощи различного ПО, а затем удалить папки 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0`, 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0`, 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0`,
перезагрузите ПК и затем установите Visual Studio повторно.